# PHP : replace character – followed with several non breaking spaces in wordpress "the_content"

Tags: html, regex, wordpress

In Wordpress, in a custom template, I have a lot of lines like that:

```
<h3>
<a name="_Toc531441816"></a> == 0
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.2.1 -&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Blabla..."
</h3>
```

There is one character `–` and 4 characters `&nbsp;`
This code come from an export from Word.

I don't need to change the beginning of the line, but I need to replace

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;`3.2.1 -&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Blabla...
```

with

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;`3.2.1 - Blabla...
```

I think that I must use regex, but I didn't find the right expression.
I can't find how to search the expression `-&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` in order to replace it by `-`

Thank you to help me,
Regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 4):

If the string to replace is exactly `–&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` you do not need regex, you can just search and replace it normally.

However, the regex would have been `–(?:&nbsp;){4}`

Comment: In fact, the code that I use in function.php is :
function replace_text_wps($str){
 $str = preg_replace('/-/','+', $str);
    return $str;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');

Nothing changes.
I think that I must replace '-' by the unicode. I tried chr(150) with no result.
I don't know what to do...

Comment: Is it perhaps an [em dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357622/whats-the-ascii-character-code-for)?

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know. In fact, I tried chr(8212) => don't work. Do you know the right expression with "preg_replace" ?

Comment: I found the code to replace "–" : &#8211; 
I found the code to replace " " : \xc2\xa0 

I use this code to replace "–": function replace_text_wps($str){
    $str = mb_ereg_replace("&#8211;", "+", $str );
    return $str;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text_wps');

Can you help me to fix the expression for "–    " (– followed by 4  non breakable spaces). In fact, how to concatenate : "&#8211;" "\xc2\xa0" "\xc2\xa0" "\xc2\xa0" "\xc2\xa0"
Thank you for your help,

Comment: The right expression is : $str = mb_ereg_replace('&#8211;(?:\xc2\xa0){4}', '+', $str );

Comment: So, it was in fact an [en dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/en-dash.html), good to know. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

The right expressions to replace strings "–    " and "●    " by "– " and "● " are:
 For "non breakable space": $str = mb_ereg_replace('–(?:\xc2\xa0){4}', '– ', $str );
 For "black circle": $str = mb_ereg_replace('\xE2\x97\x8F(?:\xc2\xa0){4}', '● ', $str );