# String unicode decimal codes convert whole

Tags: java

I have a string like `4,0 &#151; 10,0` I need to decode it to: `4,0 — 10,0`
this code can be checked in https://www.codetable.net/decimal/151

I tried Apache's `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava` without any luck.

Comment: Check the documentation: `unescapeJava`, as the name says, handles *Java* escape sequences. What you have is a HTML entity. Try using `unescapeHtml4`.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [What is the difference between EM Dash #151; and #8212;?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631406/what-is-the-difference-between-em-dash-151-and-8212)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a numerical entity, common in HTML, XML, and their base, SGML.

Try apache's `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML*`. This will also take care of named entities like `&mdash;`.

Or do it yourself:

```
Pattern entityPattern = Pattern.compile("\\&#(\\d+);");
String s = "4,0 &#151; 10,0";
s = entityPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll(mr
        -> new String(int[] {Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1))}, 0, 1);
```

This does create a string with one Unicode code point of 151.
For hexadecimal numeric entities:

```
Pattern entityPattern = Pattern.compile ("\\&#x([\\da-f]+);",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String s = "4,0 &#x97; 10,0";
s = entityPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll(mr
        -> new String(int[] {Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1), 16)}, 0, 1);
```

If you got this string from an HTML form when the user entered/pasted special characters, you forgot in the form:

```
<form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Without this, special characters are converted to numeric entities.

This assumes that the web server already uses UTF-8 for its pages.

Comment: It’s `Pattern.compile`, not `Pattern.compiler`. And there is no reason to use `[x]` to match an `x`, as you can just use `x` for that. Further, you might want to consume the semicolon if there is one. By the way, you can also use `Integer.parseInt(s, mr.start(1), mr.end(1), 16)` to avoid substring creation.

Comment: @Holger I was too much hurrying, no more stackoverflow for me today. I first wanted to do `[xX]` but then came at casse-insensitive for the hex letters. Semicolon is required (though I sometimes saw them missing).

Comment: Afaik, HTML allows to omit the semicolon if the entity is not followed by a word character, but the processor obviously has to consume it if present.